# Why does varying n_fft change the range of x axis values when plotting STFT?

Tags: fft, python, stft

I am using `librosa.stft` to apply an STFT to an audio sample and display a spectogram of the results when using different sampling windows (`n_fft = 1000` and `n_fft = 3000`). I am curious why the different sampling windows results in different range of values used on the x axis? The original audio sample is 4 seconds long.

```
# read the .wav file, print sample rate for reference
audio, sample_rate = librosa.load("voice.wav")
print('sampling rate:', sample_rate)

# perform stft using librosa module for given N values
# the parameter n_fft is where we specify value for N
audio_stft_1000 = np.abs(librosa.stft(audio, n_fft=1000))
audio_stft_3000 = np.abs(librosa.stft(audio, n_fft=3000))

# create plots according to Librosa documentation

# N = 1000
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
img = librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(audio_stft_1000,
                                                       ref=np.max),
                               y_axis='log', x_axis='s', ax=ax,
                               sr=sample_rate, n_fft=1000)
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax, format="%+2.0f dB")
ax.set_title('Power spectrogram N = 1000')

# N = 3000
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
img = librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(audio_stft_3000,
                                                       ref=np.max),
                               y_axis='log', x_axis='s', ax=ax,
                               sr=sample_rate, n_fft=3000)
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax, format="%+2.0f dB")
ax.set_title('Power spectrogram N = 3000')

# Show the plots
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [Librosa Specshow documentation](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.display.specshow.html),
you need to specify the `hop_length` in your call to `librosa.specshow()` to get the correct time axis.

Since you didn't specify `hop_length` in your `librosa.stft()` call, it defaulted to `winlength//4`, which in your case is `nfft//4` (see [Librosa stft documentation](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.stft.html)).

Try:

```
Nfft = 1000 # or 3000
img = librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(audio_stft_1000,
                                                   ref=np.max),
                           y_axis='log', x_axis='s', ax=ax,
                           sr=sample_rate, n_fft=Nfft , hop_length=Nfft//4)
```